# Use asynchrony with GeckoFX web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, web, browser, geckofx

I have a problem, I am trying to work with a custom webbrowser for a specific website.

The problem I am having with GeckoFX is that some times I need to wait for DocumentCompleted to continue with execution of particular methods.
I don't want to put all my code into one large DocumentCompleted event, as that seems silly and wrong.

I got the code to work by using the Application.DoEvents() as follows, but I read that this is not a right way to go, and that webbrowser should be best run as async.

```
 private void AddNewTab(string tmsAddress) //add a new browser to my form
    {
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        browserTabControl.TabPages.Insert(browserTabControl.TabCount - 1, tab);
        GeckoWebBrowser browser = new GeckoWebBrowser();
        tab.Controls.Add(browser);
        tmsBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tmsBrowser.Navigate(address);


        tmsBrowser.DocumentCompleted += new EventHandler<Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs>(tmsBrowser_DocumentCompleted);
    }
```

Navigation on the page is manual, i.e. users work with the page normally, but from time to time they can use a shortcut button to get somewhere.

```
private void someButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {          
            GeckoWebBrowser browser = getCurrentBrowser();

            //get some data from the page here

            OpenPageInContentFrame(address + parameter1 + parameter2); //I need to wait for this page to load and then do HighlightItemRow()

            while (!eventHandled) //documentCompleted events sets the bool as 'true'
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
            }
            HighlightItemRow(browser, parameter1);
        }
    }
```

I wanted to go with ManualResetEvents instead of while() and Application.DoEvents(), but using manResEvent.WaitOne() causes the whole application to freeze, including the navigation, so the page never actually loads. I think this must be because it's all in a single thread, I don't know how to make it working - I never used anything async etc.